# Unexpected end of JSON input in Http get request from Angular 2 to Codeigniter

Tags: json, angular, get, codeigniter-3

Angular 2 with Codeigniter Hello World Program running perfectly. But
I am getting error "Unexpected end of JSON input" while sending Http get request from Angular 2 to Codeigniter Controller "Entry.php"
Plunker code is at this link:

https://plnkr.co/edit/MHVVkWwFqEggqSI5b6B2?p=info

Same code is pasted here also:
   app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }            from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }       from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { AppComponent }        from './app.component';
import { EntryService }        from './entry.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  exports: [ // export for the DemoModule
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [ EntryService], 
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { EntryService} from './entry.service';

@Component({  
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <h3>{{ errorMsg }} </h3>      
      <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let s of scripts">{{ s.price }}</li>
      </ul>
  `,
})

class formEntry{  
  constructor(price: number, qty: number){}    
}
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    errorMsg: string;
    data: formEntry;
    constructor(private _entService: EntryService) { }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log('In OnInit: ');        
        this._entService.getData()
            .subscribe(data => this.data = data,
                        resError => this.errorMsg = resError);            
    }
}
```

entry.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response}  from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class EntryService { 

     constructor(private _http: Http) { } 

     getData(){

        let myUrl = 'http://localhost/analy/entry/getData';
        return this._http.get(myUrl)
            .map((res: Response ) => res.json())
            .catch(this._errorHandler);
      } 
      _errorHandler(error: Response){
          console.error(error);
          return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
      }
}
```

Entry.php

```
class Entry extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    }

    function getData(){
        $data = array('price' => 999,
               'qty' => 8);                
        $jdata = json_encode($data);                       
        return ($jdata);
    }
}
```

I am using webpack 2. The code is not working at plnkr but on my system. But it is working perfectly for mydata.json file but giving error for get request to "entry/getData" (from entry.service.ts). 
getData is method in Entry.php controller.

What can be the possible cause and what is possible solution..???
Please any one can please help me out to resolve the problem.

Comment: Have you checked your browser network tab, what you are actually receiving?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to parse a null value as a JSON

```
return this._http.get(myUrl)
        .map((res: Response ) => res.json())
        .catch(this._errorHandler);
```

If res is null/undefined/empty string you will get the error. Just check for the value of `res` before doing `res.json()` and you won't get the error. To be sure of this make a `console.log(res)` before trying to parse it.

Answer (score 16):

Just ran into this issue with angular 4 when I upgraded to use the new **HttpClient** from **@angular/common/http**

The interesting thing with **HttpClient** is that it automatically runs .json() on your responses.  This causes problems when the api returns back an empty response. 
 You'll then get the **Unexpected end of json** error. The solution is to set responseType as text:

```
http.get(url, { responseType: 'text' })
```

Comment: Thanks. What I did is interceptor where I transform the request with `responseType: 'text'` and then handle the response and parse it manually with `try catch`, so that I don't get response errors on empty responses with status code 200.

Comment: On my latest project I switched my status codes to 204 (No Content) instead of the try catch route on the interceptor which does not run the .json().  Since there is actually No Content which must be where they were going with the implementation.  Not sure which is really the right implementation though and some people probably cannot go back and change all their status codes.

Comment: @HristoEnev, do you mind sharing the solution you came up with?

Comment: @EugeneKulabuhov I have added a Gist with my interceptor [here](https://gist.github.com/henev/abce6bd2cf1f59b3ab9799952dbac651)